# Setting up reference lines on the x axis in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have been trying this for a couple of days but not able to find solution for it. I have a time series data which comes every 5 minutes and can extend for days. I am quiet new to D3 and Java Script. It took me some time to build it. Following is a link of the jsfiddle, i have been working on:

https://jsfiddle.net/adityap16/d61gtadm/2/

Code:

```
var data = [
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:45:00.000Z", "value": 80}
];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.mytime = parseDate(d.mytime);
        });
//var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:50 },
var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:50 },
height = 200,
width = 800;
var color =  "green";
var xaxis_param = "mytime";
var yaxis_param = "value"
var params1 =  {margin:margin,height:height,width:width, color: color, xaxis_param:xaxis_param, yaxis_param :yaxis_param};
draw_graph(data,params1);




function  draw_graph(data,params){


    //Get the margin 
    var xaxis_param = params.xaxis_param;
    var yaxis_param = params.yaxis_param;
    var color_code = params.color;
    var margin = params.margin;
    var height = params.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        width = params.width - margin.left - margin.right;

    console.log("1")

    var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){
        return d[xaxis_param]});
    console.log("2")
    var y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){
        return d[yaxis_param]});

    var x_scale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(x_extent)
        .range([0,width]);

    console.log("3")

    var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,y_extent[1]])
        .range([height,0]);



    //Line
    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x_scale(d[xaxis_param]);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y_scale(d[yaxis_param]);
        });
    var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                    .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
                    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')');
            myChart
                    .append('svg:path')
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr('class', 'line')
                    .attr("d",lineGen)
                    .attr('stroke', color_code)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                    .attr('fill', 'none');


    var legend = myChart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + 5 + "," + (height - 25) + ")")

        legend.append("rect")
          .style("fill", color_code)
          .attr("width", 20)
          .attr("height", 20);

        legend.append("text")
          .text(yaxis_param)
          .attr("x", 25)
          .attr("y", 12);

    var vGuideScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,y_extent[1]])
        .range([height, 0])

    var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(vGuideScale)
        .orient('left')
        .ticks(5)


    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x_scale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(d3.time.minute, 5);

  myChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(hAxis);

  myChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(vAxis)


}
```

I am currently stumped with two problems.

a.)I have to place vertical markers for end of each day. How to place vertical lines to show these transition (markers) from one day to another (just a simple black vertical line would do?

b.) Can we deal with missing data suppose i don't get data for a day, can i get blanks for that period of time and straight away plot the next day data. (This one is not that important)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/d61gtadm/3/

This is how you can achieve the desired results:

**Problem a.) Vertical ticks for each day:**

First, create a new major axis and set the `tickSize` to `-height`, so the ticks go all the way through your chart:

```
var majorAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x_scale)
  .orient('bottom')      
  .ticks(d3.time.day, 1)
  .tickSize(-height);
```

and then create the corresponding svg element:

```
  myChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis major")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(majorAxis);
```

Then remove the label for the major ticks(you don't want them to overlap):

```
.axis.major text {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is a nice example by M. Bostock himself: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349486

---

**Problem B.) Missing Data**

Set [.defined()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined) on the line:

```
var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d[yaxis_param]; })    
    .x(function (d) {
        return x_scale(d[xaxis_param]);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y_scale(d[yaxis_param]);
    });
```

Here is an example on how to deal with gaps in your data: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090

Comment: Hey @kmandov Thanks alot for the answer!  In your jsfiddle you are also getting a line at 12:05AM on the next day. How do you omit that, Thanks again?

Comment: I feel it might be the y axis of the major axis but not entirely sure. Thanks again!

Comment: You can set outerTickSize to 0 to remove the outer ticks on the major axis. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d61gtadm/4/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @kmandov. Another question i had was about missing data. What if i don't even have time stamp with null values. But i know that i would have data after every 5 minutes (ex. 11.50 pm , value: 78. 12:00 am, value:80, i am missing time stamp of 11:55 here.) I can go about doing this by initialisation another array with defined time stamps and populating that array but is there some other way. Thanks again !!

Comment: Could you please, ask this as a separate question and provide a jsfiddle illustrating the issue. This will make it useful for other users with the same question and will make it easier for me and others to answer.

Comment: Hey Following is the link for the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304042/d3js-interpolating-missing-time-value-as-null-in-time-series-data

Comment: Hey @kmandov , I have also tried following way but its not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307553/compare-two-time-objects-in-d3-js