# D3JS: Interpolating missing time value as null in time series data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot a time series data using D3 and running into issues with missing timestamps and width adjustment in it. The data usually comes after every 5 minutes but for some reason sometimes you can have no timestamp. (Ex. after 11:45 AM next time stamp would be 23:45). I want to have a gap in the middle instead of a line connecting them for that time period. I think i have to place a null value after every 5 minutes in a new array and use it to plot the graph. Please let me know how to go about it as i am new to d3 and java script in general

[Working jsfiddle to illustrate the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/adityap16/d61gtadm/5/)

Code:

```
var data = [
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T11:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T11:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T11:45:00.000Z", "value": 80}
];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.mytime = parseDate(d.mytime);
        });
//var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:50 },
var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:50 },
height = 200,
width = 800;
var color =  "green";
var xaxis_param = "mytime";
var yaxis_param = "value"
var params1 =  {margin:margin,height:height,width:width, color: color, xaxis_param:xaxis_param, yaxis_param :yaxis_param};
draw_graph(data,params1);




function  draw_graph(data,params){


    //Get the margin 
    var xaxis_param = params.xaxis_param;
    var yaxis_param = params.yaxis_param;
    var color_code = params.color;
    var margin = params.margin;
    var height = params.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        width = params.width - margin.left - margin.right;

    console.log("1")

    var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){
        return d[xaxis_param]});
    console.log("2")
    var y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){
        return d[yaxis_param]});

    var x_scale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(x_extent)
        .range([0,width]);

    console.log("3")

    var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,y_extent[1]])
        .range([height,0]);



    //Line
    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x_scale(d[xaxis_param]);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y_scale(d[yaxis_param]);
        });
    var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                    .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
                    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')');
            myChart
                    .append('svg:path')
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr('class', 'line')
                    .attr("d",lineGen)
                    .attr('stroke', color_code)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                    .attr('fill', 'none');


    var legend = myChart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + 5 + "," + (height - 25) + ")")

        legend.append("rect")
          .style("fill", color_code)
          .attr("width", 20)
          .attr("height", 20);

        legend.append("text")
          .text(yaxis_param)
          .attr("x", 25)
          .attr("y", 12);

    var vGuideScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,y_extent[1]])
        .range([height, 0])

    var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(vGuideScale)
        .orient('left')
        .ticks(5)


    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x_scale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(d3.time.minute, 5);

  myChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(hAxis);

  myChart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(vAxis)


}
```

Edit:
Below is the image for data set (As you can see when i have null value the graph is discontinuous but in actual data i wont have the timestamps for those null values it would go from 23:45 to 00:00)

```
var data = [{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:50:00.000Z", "value": null},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:55:00.000Z", "value": null},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:05:00.000Z", "value": 85}
];
```

[image]

Comment: This is the section which controls the tick on x axis. `.ticks(d3.time.minute, 5);` you may remove it and get ticks like this https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ytaoyjro/  or update it as you please.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. The ticks are not the problem. I want to have null values and not a line connecting the time when i don't have data in the middle (Currently the line is connecting 01/12, 11:45 to 02/12, 11:45 even when we have no data in the middle.

Comment: so whats you requirement... the line should be discontinuous? can you show screen shot base d on the data set you have put.

Comment: Yes i would like it to be discontinuous. I have added an image of what i want to do. Also how to manipulate the number of ticks ideally i would want them to be 5 minutes but if its cluttered turn it into something else.

Comment: I think may be you have to write a code to insert the null value when the date changes.

Comment: yeah, i have been trying that something like (max_date(in minute) - min_date(in minute) / 5. And then using this value to populate a new array but me being new to java script and d3. I haven't been able to code it properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107723/discussion-between-aditya-patel-and-cyril).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar by grouping the data together based on some fixed timespan, I think in your case it would be 15 minutes. Something like this:

```
function group_data_missing (arr) {
    // Group the data into buckets so that missing data is handled properly
    var timespan;
    //this gives 15 minutes in milliseconds
    timespan = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    var dg = [];
    var group = [arr[0]];
    for (var i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].date.getTime() - arr[i-1].date.getTime() > timespan) {
        dg.push(group);
        group = [];
      } else { 
        group.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    dg.push(group);
    return dg;
  }
```

This will create an array of arrays, each one being a line segment that is continuous up to 15 minutes. Then just plot each one separately.

Alternatively, if you have a continuous range of dates with some of the actual values that are null, you can use the [`.defined` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined) on the line definition.

Comment: In the end i used .defined method .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, you'll have to separate the data.

`d3`'s `line` function interprets a list of data as coordinates for a single line, no matter the distance between 2 points. Thus, if you would like to show a gap between 2 lines (which actually represent 2 separate lines), you will need to draw them separately.

See a fork of your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpkesycr/) with working example.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting approach. Can you suggest a way that the code does the separation dynamically, if the difference between time stamps is more than 5 minutes?

Comment: it depends on how do you update your existing data list? you might save the latest timestamp and a reference to the latest line object and in case the difference between the new and the latest timestamps is greater than 5 minutes, just `push` to data a new object, otherwise, append to saved reference of the line object

Comment: I will always get the data in an array with all the data. So i am assuming that i would have to find these gaps from the array given.

Comment: I thought you will update data continuously. but in case you'll get all data at once, it's even easier, although the approach is pretty similar. Compare a timestamp with the previous one and in case it's greater than X, push a new object that will represent a new line.