# Compare two time objects in D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

In D3.js i am currently trying to populate an empty array (array contains only time stamp after every 5 minutes) based on data array contains that time or not . If data array contains the time, it should copy the value otherwise null. But when i am trying to compare the two time objects its not working correctly.

Following is the code (the current code is not copying values but printing to make debugging easier):

```
var data = [{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:05:00.000Z", "value": 85}
];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.mytime = parseDate(d.mytime);
 });

var act_data = [];

  var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){
      return d['mytime']});

  time_arr = d3.time.minute.range(x_extent[0],x_extent[1],5);
  for(var key in time_arr){
  var temp;
  temp = contains(data,time_arr[key],'mytime');
}


function contains(data,value,variable)
{
  var i =data.length;
  while(i--){

   if (data[i][variable] === value)
   {
    console.log('found');
    return i;
   } 
  }
  return false;
}
```

Output should be this:

```
data = [{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:50:00.000Z", "value": null},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:55:00.000Z", "value": null},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:05:00.000Z", "value": 85}
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use (**D3 3.x API**)

- [`d3.time.format`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format) to parse and format your dates
- [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_extent) to determine the boundaries of your timestamps
- [`d3.time.scale`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Scales.md) to generate the ticks you want to output
- and [`d3.map`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_map) to hash your input and determine if a value exists

This gives us

```
var data = [...];

// for parsing and formatting
var timeformat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

// range to operate on
var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){ 
    return timeformat.parse(d.mytime); 
});

// scale representing the time stamps
var scale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(extent) // the boundaries
    .ticks(d3.time.minute, 5); // 5 minutes intervals

// easier to determine if a value exists
var hashed = d3.map(data, function(d) { return d.mytime; });

// or if your version < 3.5
/*
var hashed = d3.map();
data.forEach(function(d) { 
    hashed.set(d.mytime, d);
});
*/


// transforms the scale into the desired output
var res = scale.map(function(t) {
    var ft = timeformat(t);
    return {
        mytime: ft,
        value: (hashed.has(ft)) ? hashed.get(ft).value : null
    };
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/qxcLry8z/

```js
var data = [
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:05:00.000Z", "value": 85}
];


var timeformat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){ 
    return timeformat.parse(d.mytime); 
});

var scale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(extent)
    .ticks(d3.time.minute, 5);
  
var hashed = d3.map();
data.forEach(function(d) { 
    hashed.set(d.mytime, d);
});
  
var res = scale.map(function(t) {
    var ft = timeformat(t);
    return {
        mytime: ft,
        value: (hashed.has(ft)) ? hashed.get(ft).value : null
    };
});

var $table = $('<table></table>'); 
res.forEach(function(d) {
    $table.append('<tr><td>'+d.mytime+'</td><td>'+d.value+'</td></tr>')
});
$('body').append($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's exactly what i was looking for. But when i am running in the local machine. Somehow i am getting all the values as 'null'. I checked out the jsfiddle and copied the code but still its giving null.

Comment: I actually just copied your code and ran it locally and did console.log(res[1]) . So not sure why this is not working. I am using a downloaded version of d3(which is only 2 weeks old).

Comment: Your version of d3 is probably < 3.5, that 's where `d3.map(array)` has been added and why you get null values. I'll try to write an alternative.

Comment: I've added a version that should be compatible with d3 prior to 3.5. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/qxcLry8z/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d.mydate});//get the max min limit
var data1 = []; make an empty array
for (var i =0; i < data.length -1; i++){
    var diff = data[i + 1].mytime.getTime() - data[i].mytime.getTime();
    if (diff <= 300000){ //less than equal to 5 minutes
        data1.push(data[i])
    } else { //greater than 5 minutes
      var t1 = new Date(data[i].mytime.getTime() + 300000)
        var t2 = new Date(data[i +1].mytime.getTime() - 300000)
        data1.push({"mytime": t1, "value": null})
        data1.push({"mytime": t2, "value": null})
    }
}
data1.push(data[data.length -1]); //take the last value as it was not processed
data = data1
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ytaoyjro/1/)

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of ES6 there are more options available to tackle the task. Depending on the browser versions one needs to support, the following code might be a viable approach. I have successfully tested this on Chrome 49 and FF 45.

The solution adds a custom [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to the `data` array that will return a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) object which conforms to the new [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). This will iterate over the `data` array and fill in any gaps it detects along the way with objects having their `value` property set to `null`.

The snippet further makes use of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to create a new array and fill it by implicitly invoking the iterator.

```
data[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  var i = 0,
      t = this[0],
      nextStep;
  while (i < this.length) {
    nextStep = t.mytime.getTime() + FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MS;
    yield t = nextStep < this[i].mytime.getTime()
      ? {"mytime": new Date(nextStep), "value": null}
      : this[i++];
  }
};


// use the spread operator to create a new array which will implicitly call
// the iterator
data = [...data];
```

Have a look at the following snippet for a demo working in Chrome 49 and FF 45:

```js
"use strict";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Setup
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MS = 5 * 60 * 1000;

var data = [
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:05:00.000Z", "value": 85}
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.mytime = parse(d.mytime);
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implement iterator to fill in gaps in data array
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

data[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  var i = 0,
      t = this[0],
      nextStep;
  while (i < this.length) {
    nextStep = t.mytime.getTime() + FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MS;
    yield t = nextStep < this[i].mytime.getTime()
      ? {"mytime": new Date(nextStep), "value": null}
      : this[i++];
  }
};

// use the spread operator to create a new array which will implicitly call the iterator
data = [...data];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Just output below.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//console.dir(data);

d3.select("body").append("div")
 .style({
    "font-family": "monospace",
    "white-space": "pre"
  })
  .text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, you may provide an explicit implementation of the [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterator) protocol. This is a little more verbose to write but does not change the overall concept:

```
data[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  var self = this;
  return {
    i: 0,
    t: self[0],
    next() {
      if (this.i < self.length) {
        var nextStep = this.t.mytime.getTime() + FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MS;
        this.t = nextStep < self[this.i].mytime.getTime()
          ? { "mytime": new Date(nextStep), "value": null }
          : self[this.i++];
        return {
          value: this.t,
          done:  false
        }
      } else {
        return {
          done: true
        }
      } 
    }
  }
};
```

The following snippet demonstrates this:

```js
"use strict";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Setup
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MS = 5 * 60 * 1000;

var data = [
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:10:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:15:00.000Z", "value": 67},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:20:00.000Z", "value": 70},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:25:00.000Z", "value": 64},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:30:00.000Z", "value": 72},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:35:00.000Z", "value": 75},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:40:00.000Z", "value": 71},
{"mytime": "2015-12-01T23:45:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z", "value": 80},
{"mytime": "2015-12-02T00:05:00.000Z", "value": 85}
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.mytime = parse(d.mytime);
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implement iterator to fill in gaps in data array
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

data[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  var self = this;
  return {
    i: 0,
    t: self[0],
    next() {
      if (this.i < self.length) {
        var nextStep = this.t.mytime.getTime() + FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MS;
        this.t = nextStep < self[this.i].mytime.getTime()
          ? { "mytime": new Date(nextStep), "value": null }
          : self[this.i++];
        return {
          value: this.t,
          done:  false
        }
      } else {
        return {
          done: true
        }
      } 
    }
  }
};

// use the spread operator to create a new array which will implicitly call the iterator
data = [...data];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Just output below.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//console.dir(data);

d3.select("body").append("div")
 .style({
    "font-family": "monospace",
    "white-space": "pre"
  })
  .text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```